# How to return a clean error on incorrect mount with VTreeFS?

Tags: c, minix

When trying to mount a [VTreeFS](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/DevelopersGuide/VTreeFS) filesystem with a set of arguments (by using options -o when mounting) we want to let it fail cleanly if the user doesn't use the predefined arguments correctly. Currently we get this nasty error message when we do not mount the filesystem and let the main return 0. We basically want the filesystem to not be mounted if the arguments are inorrect

Current situations

> mount -t filesystemtest -o testarguments none /mnt/filesystemtest
>
> Arguments invalid
>
> RS: service 'fs_00021' exited uring initialization
>
> filesystemtest 109710 0xab6e 0x65f1 0x618d 0x6203 0x98ba 0x1010
>
> Request to RS failed: unknown error (error 302)
>
> mount: couldn't run /bin/sercie up /sbin/filesystemtest -label 'fs_00021'-args ''
>
> mount: Can't mount none on /mnt/filesystemtest/: unknown error

Preferred situation

> mount -t filesystemtest -o testarguments none /mnt/filesystemtest
>
> Arguments invalid

Basically we wan't to know how to return a clean error message, when not calling start_vtreefs like below. The below example is not our actualy code and doesn't actually use arguments, but as an example there should be a way to have this piece of code to fail always. (sorry for that):

```
#include <minix/drivers.h>
#include <minix/vtreefs.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void my_init_hook(void)
{       
        /* This hook will be called once, after VTreeFS has initialized.
         */
        struct inode_stat file_stat;
        struct inode *inode;

        /* We create one regular file in the root directory. The file is
         * readable by everyone, and owned by root. Its size as returned by for
         * example stat() will be zero, but that does not mean it is empty.
         * For files with dynamically generated content, the file size is
         * typically set to zero.
         */
        file_stat.mode = S_IFREG | 0444;
        file_stat.uid = 0;
        file_stat.gid = 0;
        file_stat.size = 0;
        file_stat.dev = NO_DEV;

        /* Now create the actual file. It is called "test" and does not have an
         * index number. Its callback data value is set to 1, allowing it to be
         * identified with this number later.
         */
        inode = add_inode(get_root_inode(), "test", NO_INDEX, &file_stat, 0,
                (cbdata_t) 1);

        assert(inode != NULL);
}

static int my_read_hook(struct inode *inode, off_t offset, char **ptr,
        size_t *len, cbdata_t cbdata)
{
        /* This hook will be called every time a regular file is read. We use
         * it to dyanmically generate the contents of our file.
         */
        static char data[26];
        const char *str;
        time_t now;

        /* We have only a single file. With more files, cbdata may help
         * distinguishing between them.
         */
        assert((int) cbdata == 1);

        /* Generate the contents of the file into the 'data' buffer. We could
         * use the return value of ctime() directly, but that would make for a
         * lousy example.
         */
        time(&now);

        str = ctime(&now);

        strcpy(data, str);

        /* If the offset is beyond the end of the string, return EOF. */
        if (offset > strlen(data)) {
                *len = 0;

                return OK;
        }

        /* Otherwise, return a pointer into 'data'. If necessary, bound the
         * returned length to the length of the rest of the string. Note that
         * 'data' has to be static, because it will be used after this function
         * returns.
         */
        *ptr = data + offset;

        if (*len > strlen(data) - offset)
                *len = strlen(data) - offset;

        return OK;
}

/* The table with callback hooks. */
struct fs_hooks my_hooks = {
        my_init_hook,
        NULL, /* cleanup_hook */
        NULL, /* lookup_hook */
        NULL, /* getdents_hook */
        my_read_hook,
        NULL, /* rdlink_hook */
        NULL  /* message_hook */
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* The call above never returns. This just keeps the compiler happy. */
    if (argc == 1) {
        // We want it to fail right now!!!!
        printf("Arguments invalid. (pass option with -o)");
    }
    else {
        struct inode_stat root_stat;

        /* Fill in the details to be used for the root inode. It will be a
         * directory, readable and searchable by anyone, and owned by root.
         */
        root_stat.mode = S_IFDIR | 0555;
        root_stat.uid = 0;
        root_stat.gid = 0;
        root_stat.size = 0;
        root_stat.dev = NO_DEV;

        /* Now start VTreeFS. Preallocate 10 inodes, which is more than we'll
         * need for this example. No indexed entries are used.
         */
        start_vtreefs(&my_hooks, 10, &root_stat, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```